# Evernote api Evernote.EDAM.Error.EDAMNotFoundException

Tags: evernote

I use evernote api to upload notes,
In the beginning it works fine, after upload 100 more notes it show errors, after that I can't upload anymore notes.

What's happened?

```
於 EvernoteSDK.ENSession.UploadNote_Create(ENSessionUploadContext context)
於 EvernoteSDK.ENSession.UploadNote_DetermineDestination(ENSessionUploadContext context)
於 EvernoteSDK.ENSession.UploadNote(ENNote note, UploadPolicy policy, ENNotebook notebook, ENNoteRef noteToReplace)
於 EvernoteSDK.ENSession.UploadNote(ENNote note, ENNotebook notebook)
於 SampleApp.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
於 C:\Users\au\Desktop\SampleApp\SampleApp\Form1.cs: 行 75
```

My code：

```
ENSession.SetSharedSessionConsumerKey("xxx", "xxx");

if (ENSession.SharedSession.IsAuthenticated == false)
{
    ENSession.SharedSession.AuthenticateToEvernote();
}
ENNote myPlainNote = new ENNote();
myPlainNote.Title = newname;
myPlainNote.Content = ENNoteContent.NoteContentWithString(Content);
ENNoteRef myPlainNoteRef = ENSession.SharedSession.UploadNote(myPlainNote, null);
```

Comment: What error did you get? Are you sure it's EDAMNotFoundException?

Comment: @kentaro yes, it shows EDAMNotFoundException.

Comment: Finally I change from production to sandbox and execute it, and change it back to production, it works.